# Segfault when importing Tensorflow

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, gpu, updates

Recently I upgraded my ubuntu to 18.04 and I am unable to import tensorflow into any python code.  Here is an example:

```
>>> import tensorflow
python3: Relink `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1' with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1' for IFUNC symbol `clock_gettime'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

There are other articles on the web related to this type of error but non of the proposed remedies work (mostly around installing opencv)[https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19375].

I have installed CUDA 10.0 which seems to be the specific release required for the version of tensorflow.

I have ensured that:

- opencv-python is installed for python3.
- That I have the latest nvidia graphics driver.
- I believe I have the correct cuda and cudaDNN libraries
- re-installed udev (hail mary pass)

I run Python 3.6.7

Here is the info for the Nivida graphics driver:

```
modinfo nvidia
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-47-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia.ko
alias:          char-major-195-*
version:        418.39
supported:      external
license:        NVIDIA
srcversion:     86171E965AC9C3AD399B033
alias:          pci:v000010DEd00000E00sv*sd*bc04sc80i00*
alias:          pci:v000010DEd*sv*sd*bc03sc02i00*
alias:          pci:v000010DEd*sv*sd*bc03sc00i00*
depends:        ipmi_msghandler
retpoline:      Y
name:           nvidia
vermagic:       4.15.0-47-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           NvSwitchRegDwords:NvSwitch regkey (charp)
parm:           NVreg_Mobile:int
parm:           NVreg_ResmanDebugLevel:int
parm:           NVreg_RmLogonRC:int
parm:           NVreg_ModifyDeviceFiles:int
parm:           NVreg_DeviceFileUID:int
parm:           NVreg_DeviceFileGID:int
parm:           NVreg_DeviceFileMode:int
parm:           NVreg_UpdateMemoryTypes:int
parm:           NVreg_InitializeSystemMemoryAllocations:int
parm:           NVreg_UsePageAttributeTable:int
parm:           NVreg_MapRegistersEarly:int
parm:           NVreg_RegisterForACPIEvents:int
parm:           NVreg_CheckPCIConfigSpace:int
parm:           NVreg_EnablePCIeGen3:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableMSI:int
parm:           NVreg_TCEBypassMode:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableStreamMemOPs:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableBacklightHandler:int
parm:           NVreg_RestrictProfilingToAdminUsers:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableUserNUMAManagement:int
parm:           NVreg_MemoryPoolSize:int
parm:           NVreg_KMallocHeapMaxSize:int
parm:           NVreg_VMallocHeapMaxSize:int
parm:           NVreg_IgnoreMMIOCheck:int
parm:           NVreg_NvLinkDisable:int
parm:           NVreg_RegistryDwords:charp
parm:           NVreg_RegistryDwordsPerDevice:charp
parm:           NVreg_RmMsg:charp
parm:           NVreg_GpuBlacklist:charp
parm:           NVreg_AssignGpus:charp
```

Here are the versions of python libraries installed:

```
pip3 install tensorflow-gpu
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-gpu in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (1.13.1)
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio>=1.8.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (1.19.0)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.6.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (3.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard<1.14.0,>=1.13.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (1.13.1)
Requirement already satisfied: astor>=0.6.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (0.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.26 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (0.30.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (1.15.3)
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor>=1.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-preprocessing>=1.0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (1.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py>=0.1.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (0.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: gast>=0.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (0.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-estimator<1.14.0rc0,>=1.13.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (1.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-applications>=1.0.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (1.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from protobuf>=3.6.1->tensorflow-gpu) (39.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=0.11.15 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorboard<1.14.0,>=1.13.0->tensorflow-gpu) (0.15.2)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown>=2.6.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorboard<1.14.0,>=1.13.0->tensorflow-gpu) (3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: mock>=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow-estimator<1.14.0rc0,>=1.13.0->tensorflow-gpu) (2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from keras-applications>=1.0.6->tensorflow-gpu) (2.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pbr>=0.11 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from mock>=2.0.0->tensorflow-estimator<1.14.0rc0,>=1.13.0->tensorflow-gpu) (5.1.0)
```

tensorflow dump tool output:

```
== cat /etc/issue ===============================================
Linux mega 4.15.0-47-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 13 10:44:52 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
VERSION="18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic

== are we in docker =============================================
No

== compiler =====================================================
c++ (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


== uname -a =====================================================
Linux mega 4.15.0-47-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 13 10:44:52 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

== check pips ===================================================
msgpack-numpy                 0.4.1              
numpy                         1.15.3             
protobuf                      3.7.1              
tensorflow                    1.13.1             
tensorflow-estimator          1.13.0             
tensorflow-gpu                1.13.1             

== check for virtualenv =========================================
False
```

I attempted to include the tensorflow diag script output but went over the stack exchange message limit.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? Just faced the same problem :(

Comment: No I was unable to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this counts as an answer, but 2.0-alpha does not have this problem.